# Key components and other stuff to consider when creating a photo editor in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, components, key, flash-builder

Well the question says it all...

What are the key components and other stuff to consider when creating a **simple** photo editor in Flex 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too large of a question to answer easily.  If I had to recommend one gotcha it would be to watch out for memory leaks in your Bitmap.  Make sure to call dispose() on your BitmapData when you no longer need it.  If you don't do that, I've seen programs have memory problems especially if they have lots of images loading.